# Как использовать INF файл внутри приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Каким образом можно взаимодействовать с INF файлами для их запуска внутри приложения, или запуска INF файлов из внешнего источника?

Например, приложение содержит ресурс, INF файл, его нужно запустить, чтобы установить драйвер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как этот код должен работать, но не работает:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MySoft
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("Setupapi.dll", EntryPoint = "InstallHinfSection", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void InstallHinfSection([In] IntPtr hwnd, [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer, int nCmdShow);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, Properties.Resources._INF, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос примерным кодом, который не работает...

Answer (score 3):

Открываем `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.inf`, переходим к `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inffile\shell\Install\command`, смотрим командную строку:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "%1"
```

Итого вам надо выполнить:

```
InfDefaultInstall "C:\Path\To\MyDriver.inf"
```

Это если вы на Windows 10. У предыдущих осей могут быть другие команды.

Если вы настаиваете на использовании функции `InstallHinfSection`, то внимательно [прочитайте документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa376957.aspx). Там "командная строка" весьма специфическая и включает имя секции и параметры в дополнение к абсолютному пути к файлу (как форма костылей для запуска через RunDll32). Мои телепатические способности подсказывают, что строка у вас в ресурсах выглядит иначе.